# How to alter a try-catch exception to catch a number not within the requested range OR a number within the requested range that is a decimal?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am writing a large program that is supposed to eventually serve as a lemonade stand game. I have 6 different classes for this project. Currently, I have two small problems with the menu class that I created to output the initial menu of the game.

My first question is it the printf is formatted correctly. 
My main question is how I would alter the try catch exception so that it will catch a user input that is not within the range I requested (1-3) or that is a decimal within that range(2.5). Possibly a try catch exception won't work in this scenario (although that is what my teacher asked us to do).

Here is a portion of my menu class (the portion with the problems):

```
     public int initialMenu()
{

    boolean getValues = true;

    while (getValues){

    try{

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Lemonade Stand Game!");
    System.out.println("How many days would you like to run your lemonade stand for?");
    System.out.printf("%3s\t%3s%n%3s\t%3s%n%3s\t%3s%n", "Enter 1:" , "10 days", "Enter 2:", "20 days", "Enter 3:", "30 days"); //change this
    userEnteredNumber = reader.nextInt();


    }

    catch(Exception e) //how to change try catch exception so that it will catch < 1 or > 3 or a decimal input
    {
        System.out.println("Error in number format. Enter a valid number from the choices (1,2,3)");
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to detect the various conditions and then throw the exceptions yourself. You do not test exceptions for specific values that might have triggered them.

You don't necessarily have to define new Exception types, for instance, you might decide that something that is out of range should throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Then you can add a catch for each specific exception type, if you want to have different recovery strategies for each.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question in the most generic sense, yes there is an error in the printf.

Please don't use StackOverflow to ask for help with homework.